# Обработка нажатия

Tags: java, android

На просторах интернета столкнулся с двумя интересными конструкциями, и хоть я пользуюсь только первой, интерес всё же взял вверх, какую из них лучше **использовать** в своих проектах? Допускаю что вопрос банален, но не спросить я не могу;)
Итак, первая конструкция:

```
private OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do something when the button is clicked
    }
};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedValues) {
    ...
    // Capture our button from layout
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.close);
    // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
    button.setOnClickListener(myListener);
    ...
}
```

И вторая не менее интересная конструкция:

```
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/butHello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Поздороваться"
    android:onClick="butHello_Click" />
```

Здесь мы определили событие onClick <*считается ли это вообще из ряда "**Best Practice**"?*

После чего прописали метод(к нашему .xml):

```
public void butHello_Click(View v){
    edtext.setText("Здравствуй, друг");
}
```

Comment: Я не являюсь Android разработчиком, но во втором варианте вы просто используете XML и все )

Comment: @kxxko ниже написан метод к данному xml;) его же мы и вставляем в MainActivity например

Comment: Ну да, а в чем вопрос собственно ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Я бы не рекомендовал использовать второй вариант по следующим причинам:

1. Его можно использовать только с Activity. Фрагменты в пролете.
2. Вам в любом случае не отказаться от использования первого варианта, а одни и те же действия лучше делать одним способом, соответственно раз от первого не отказаться - лучше отказаться от второго.
3. Так можно подписаться только на onClick, остальные калбеки в пролете, так что опять таки для однообразия лучше и на onClick подписываться так же как на остальные.
4. Если вы будете использовать второй вариант, то когда ваш код возьмет человек не пользующийся этим способом ему будет очень сложно понять как же управление попадает в метод который вроде нигде не вызывается. Да и вы сами спустя время можете забыть где же используется метод, а Android Studio будет показывать что он нигде не используется.
5. Из предыдущего пункта так же вытекает что при рефакторинге можно переименовать метод и не заметить что он использовался в каком то xml, особенно если он использовался в нескольких вариантах разметки.

В общем моё мнение: хотите меньше проблем - не используйте второй вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Все три конструкции имеют место быть. Какую использовать? - это вопрос организации кода, если хотите знать досконально, для чего сделано подобное. Синтаксический сахар, удобство - называйте, как хотите. Чтобы ваш код был более читаемым, либо просто некоторым удобнее через XML (ведь есть разработчики, пришедшие с других языков, они могли пользоваться одним из вариантов, и если он имеется здесь - будет проще привыкнуть к новому инструменту).

Ваш вопрос не имеет определенного ответа. Это субъективная вещь и каждый делает, как посчитает нужным.

Comment: "Все три конструкции"?) Это, наверное, опечатка?) Конструкций тут две))

Comment: @Ksenia ну тут две конструкции, а вообще способа три.

Comment: а третий способ - это какой?

Comment: @Ksenia http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/button.php

Comment: @Ksenia как лихо подвёл то к третьему то способу?)

Comment: @Asgard, не, способа только два. Все способы программного назначения работают одинаково - вы создаёте класс, реализующий интерфейс, а потом передаёте его в метод setOnClickListener. Различия только видимые, в написании, а принцип тот же.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не, способа три. Способа - работают все три по одному и тому же принципу.
через XML парсится в тот же самый листенер, второй и третий способы так же имеют место быть. Если говорить с вашей позиции, то он один - это онкликлистенер. Все три - состояния одного.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Все же реализация интерфейса в классе и анонимная реализация - разные способы. И юзкейс разный.

Comment: @pavlofff, но ведь и анонимный класс - это класс)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в анонимном классе каждый кликер вы пишите индивидуально для одного `View`. При реализации интерфейса в классе, один кликер обслуживает все `View`. В этом принципиальная разница и разная реализация логики.

Comment: @pavlofff, кажется, мы спорим о разном) Я в более общем плане вопрос рассматриваю. По моему мнению, если и разделять способы на виды, то один вид это в разметке прописывать - через onClick или DataBinding, а другой - программно, реализуя интерфейс, безотносительно способа реализации.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Ну с этой точки зрения, да.

Comment: @pavlofff в метод setOnClickListener ведь передаётся не сам класс, а экземпляр класса? Тогда какая разница, экземпляр явного или анонимного класса?

Comment: @NickVolynkin разница [в этом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568237/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f/568240?noredirect=1#comment744539_568240)